# Adding certain code to a class for button click

Tags: java, methods

Hi within my GUI I have a Button that opens a secondary GUI and would like to add this code into a class using a method, as i am using Netbeans i can just put the code straight into the button {}

Here is my code.

```
 public class nextgui {
    public int rungui() {
        int confirmCombat = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you would like to set your main trait as Combat?", "Confirm Combat", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); { 
        if (confirmCombat == 0) { 
            this.setVisible(false); 
            gui mainJframe = new gui(); 
            mainJframe.setVisible(true); 
        } 
    } 
        return;
```

When I place this code within my new class and method it throws an error saying cannot find symbol, I'm not so good with Java thanks for your time and patience...

Comment: `return;` statement you are supposed to return an int change it to
`return 1;`

Comment: this.setVisible(false); still throws me an error

Comment: you cant use `setVisible(false); ` in a normal class your class should extend `Jframe`. then it will work

Comment: thank you that has fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class nextgui extends Jframe {
        public int rungui() {
            int confirmCombat = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you would like to set your main trait as Combat?", "Confirm Combat", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); { 
            if (confirmCombat == 0) { 
                this.setVisible(false); 
                gui mainJframe = new gui(); 
                mainJframe.setVisible(true); 
            } 
        } 
            return 1; 
}
```

there are sevral things wrong with the code if your method has a return type you are supposed to return a value in your case your method is declared to return an int `int rungui()` an your return statement should return an int.
and the other thing you cant call setVisible true on a normal class
your class should extend `Jframe` then you can call this method.
 `public class nextgui extends Jframe`

Answer (score 0):

i have modified your code below

```
public int rungui() {
    int confirmCombat = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you would like to set your main trait as Combat?", "Confirm Combat", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); { 
    if (confirmCombat == 0) { 
        gui mainJframe = new gui(); 
        mainJframe.setVisible(true); 
    } 
return 0;
}
```

the method rungui() has a return type of int. so you should return an integer depending on your requirements. 
if an integer return is not required just change is as below then (with no return.)

```
public void rungui() {
    int confirmCombat = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you would like to set your main trait as Combat?", "Confirm Combat", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); { 
    if (confirmCombat == 0) { 
        gui mainJframe = new gui(); 
        mainJframe.setVisible(true); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: how can you call `this.setVisible` in a normal class

Comment: I'm keeping the setVisible() on mainJframe. I'm assuming gui class is a subclass of JFrame